# how to merge two column of a dataset to one column of other data set

Tags: r

i have two data set as follows

`full.name` is a column and first of full name is the first word of `full.name` and `country` in df1 is not correct so i want to match df1(`full.name` and `first of full name`) with column(name)of df2  if either of two column of df1 match with column of df2 then in corresponding  it should print corrected country values and if full.name`and`first of full name of df1 does not match with name of df2 then it should print value of full.name`and`first of full name and NA in the value of name and corrected country

df1:

```
full.name    first of full name  country
karachi east  karachi            pakistan
phu my        phu                england
phu my        phu                india
delhi         delhi              china
west australia west              england
west australia west              australia
abu dhabai     abu               xyz
south africa   south             africa
```

and

df2:

```
name            corrected.country
karachi         pakistan 
phu my          england
delhi           India
west australia  australia
abu             dubai
```

and i want my output as

```
full.name    first of full name  country     name          corrected country
karachi east  karachi            pakistan    karachi        pakistan 
phu my        phu                england     phu my         england
phu my        phu                india       phu my         england
delhi         delhi              china       delhi          India
west australia west              england     west australia australia
west australia west              australia   west australia australia
abu dhabai     abu               xyz         abu            dubai
south africa   south             africa      NA              NA
```

i want to match `full.name` and `first of full name` of df1 to match with name of df2 if any of the df1 column matches with df2 (col-name) then in output i want  corrected country column with name column if any of df1 column matched with name column of df2 either `full.name` or `first of full name`

i known i made this lil bit complex but i really want to solve this please help

Comment: I think it would be a nice move to use punctutation when formulating your question. Helps a lot. And maybe give a reproducible example of your data e.g. by using `dput(head(df1))`  and the same with `df2`.

Comment: I am sure I am not the only one that finds this hard to read. Could you post example data.frames (i.e. first couple rows) and example output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this should work as long as there are no duplicates in your dataframe

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("full.name"= "name")), name = full.name) %>%
  dplyr::union(., mutate(inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("first.of.full.name" = "name")), name = first.of.full.name)) %>% 
       select(1,2,3,5,4) #just ordering the columns


       full.name first.of.full.name   country           name corrected.country
1         phu my                phu   england         phu my           england
2         phu my                phu     india         phu my           england
3          delhi              delhi     china          delhi             India
4 west australia               west   england west australia         australia
5 west australia               west australia west australia         australia
6   karachi east            karachi  pakistan        karachi          pakistan
7     abu dhabai                abu       xyz            abu             dubai
```

When you just merge two `data.frames` the wo columns being merged on become one, so I had to find a workaround for your `name`-column still being in the result.

Beware though of the column names, when reproducing my code. But they should be the same in R.

UPDATE:

To include names not in df2:

```
> df1_2
       full.name first.of.full.name   country
1   karachi east            karachi  pakistan
2         phu my                phu   england
3         phu my                phu     india
4          delhi              delhi     china
5 west australia               west   england
6 west australia               west australia
7     abu dhabai                abu       xyz
8      Stuttgart          Stuttgart   germany

bind_rows(df3, df1_2[rowSums(sapply(1:2, function(x) df1_2[,x] %in% df2$name)) == 0,])

full.name first.of.full.name   country           name corrected.country
1         phu my                phu   england         phu my           england
2         phu my                phu     india         phu my           england
3          delhi              delhi     china          delhi             India
4 west australia               west   england west australia         australia
5 west australia               west australia west australia         australia
6   karachi east            karachi  pakistan        karachi          pakistan
7     abu dhabai                abu       xyz            abu             dubai
8      Stuttgart          Stuttgart   germany           <NA>              <NA>
```

df1_2 is your df1, with a new row, and df3 is the result from above.

Comment: Emily Kothes and my answer are different. You said you used mine. May I ask why you now accepted her answer as the correct one?

Comment: ok fine i m accepting yours but thanks both of you for your help

Comment: Thanks. If you want to leave a present to Emily as well you can upvote her answer. This is also a reward.

Comment: sorry to disturb you again can i ask you another question related to this example how can i find those values which does'nt matched with the column name in df2 but they are in df1 i m editing example can u plz help me with that

Comment: @ Humpelstielzchen can u help plz i have tried a lot of things but i m not getting exactly unmatched values

Comment: have you loaded the `dplyr`-package? `library(dplyr)`

Answer (score 0):

I start by recreating your datasets. You don't need to do this part because you already have your own data but I've included it here for the sake of others who want to reproduce the solution.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
            full.name = c("karachi east", "phu my", "phu my", "delhi",
                          "west australia", "west australia", "abu dhabai"),
   first.of.full.name = c("karachi", "phu", "phu", "delhi", "west", "west",
                          "abu"),
              country = c("pakistan", "england", "india", "china", "england",
                          "australia", "xyz"))
df2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                name = c("karachi", "phu my", "delhi", "west australia", "abu"),
   corrected.country = c("pakistan", "england", "India", "australia", "dubai")
)
```

Now, load the dplyr package. You can use inner_join to match each "key" variable (i.e. full.name and first.of.full.name) to df2, then use union() to join the two sets of data together.

```
library(dplyr)

df3 <- union(inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("first.of.full.name" = "name")) , 
      inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("full.name" = "name")))

df3
#>        full.name first.of.full.name   country corrected.country
#> 1   karachi east            karachi  pakistan          pakistan
#> 2          delhi              delhi     china             India
#> 3     abu dhabai                abu       xyz             dubai
#> 4         phu my                phu   england           england
#> 5         phu my                phu     india           england
#> 6 west australia               west   england         australia
#> 7 west australia               west australia         australia
```

If you broke that into separate steps this would be

```r
library(dplyr)

df3 <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("first.of.full.name" = "name"))
df3
#>      full.name first.of.full.name  country corrected.country
#> 1 karachi east            karachi pakistan          pakistan
#> 2        delhi              delhi    china             India
#> 3   abu dhabai                abu      xyz             dubai

df4 <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("full.name" = "name"))
df4
#>        full.name first.of.full.name   country corrected.country
#> 1         phu my                phu   england           england
#> 2         phu my                phu     india           england
#> 3          delhi              delhi     china             India
#> 4 west australia               west   england         australia
#> 5 west australia               west australia         australia

df5 <- union(df3, df4)
df5
#>        full.name first.of.full.name   country corrected.country
#> 1   karachi east            karachi  pakistan          pakistan
#> 2          delhi              delhi     china             India
#> 3     abu dhabai                abu       xyz             dubai
#> 4         phu my                phu   england           england
#> 5         phu my                phu     india           england
#> 6 west australia               west   england         australia
#> 7 west australia               west australia         australia
```

Created on 2019-02-27 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).